# Charles SSL Certificate/Windows/Chrome - The certificate is not in the Trusted root folder

Tags: windows, google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate

I am trying to use Charles on Windows with Chrome. I Installed the certificate to the user and choose the Trusted root folder. The install was successful, but I can not see the certificate in the Trusted root folder and also the responses are still encrypted. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you install the certificate to the user's certificate store or the machine's certificate store?  Edit your question to include this vital required information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: To the user's certificate.

Comment: Ok I changed it to machine's certificate and now I see it in Trusted, but the requests are still encrypted. What else should I do?